# HTML hidden frame to control navigation of visible frame

Tags: html

I wish to create a hidden frame,from which I wish to control the navigation of visible frame (like showing the content in it from different urls depending upon some logic in hidden frame)
Is it possible?
Thanks

Comment: can you show us some code what you tried.

Comment: Why wouldn't you control the navigation from the site itself?

Comment: Because the web pages to be shown are on different web server (private cloud to be exact)

Answer (score 2):

It is possible but if you do that most probably your webpage/website will be detected as harmful page!

Comment: Ok. How is it possible? And if there are security issues then it is misplaced because if the landing url is safe then any further activity on the server should be considered safe.

Comment: Hidden frames sometimes know as hacking techniques like waterhole,session hijackking ..etc.your idea is very similar with them!